# Indices tab missing on aws opensearch tab

Tags: amazon-web-services, opensearch

I have created an elasticsearch cluster on aws opensearch. The cluster is in a VPC. For some reason I am not able to see the indices tab on it. I am also not able to create indexes on my cluster using python code.
[image: Indices tab is missing]
Any idea why is it so?
I am not able to create indices on the cluster and getting a timeout error while trying to do so.

Comment: The reason you don't see indices tab is because your cluster is in VPC and that's a known limitation from aws opensearch